# How to delete all files and directory except one named directory from a specific folder in centos

Tags: bash, centos, rm

I want to delete all files and directories from a specific directory except for one directory. For the same operation I had run this command

```
# rm -R -df !(dir_name_not_to_delete)
```

It works in Ubuntu but it gives an error in CentOS; i.e.,

```
-bash: !: event not found  " what is the reason for this error"
```

What do I have to use in CentOS to get this to work?
  Is there any alternative of '!' this sign in Centos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `!(dir_name_not_to_delete)` is an extended glob.  For it to work, you need to have the extended globs option turned on.  Run:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Secondly, the specific error message that you see, `-bash: !: event not found`, means that you also have history expansion turned on.  If you don't want history expansion, it it safest to turn it off:

```
set +H
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about list everything in that folder then exclude that folder and delete everything else

```
find MYDIR -not -name EXCEPT_DIR -exec rm -rf {}\;
```

But before doing that, just test what the find command will find, ex:

```
find MYDIR -not -name EXCEPT_DIR
```